# Hiding Internationalization with the Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, internationalization, repository-pattern

I'm trying to create an internationalized shop as an example. In order to expose `Product` which has different translations for each property.

Here's my attempt, implementing only the R of CRUD at this stage. (Apologies for the amount of code)

```
void Main()
{
    var repo = new ProductRepository();

    var enGb = repo.GetProduct(1, "en-GB");

    Console.WriteLine("en-GB: {0} {1}", enGb.Name, enGb.Description);

    var enUS = repo.GetProduct(1, "en-US");

    Console.WriteLine("en-US: {0} {1}", enUS.Name, enUS.Description);
}

private static IEnumerable<HiddenProduct> hiddenProducts = new List<HiddenProduct> { new HiddenProduct { Id = 1, NameId = 1, DescriptionId = 2 } };
private static IEnumerable<Translation> translations = new List<Translation>
{
    new Translation { Id = 1, Locale = "en-GB", Text = "Hello" },
    new Translation { Id = 1, Locale = "en-US", Text = "Howdy" },
    new Translation { Id = 2, Locale = "en-GB", Text = "World" },
    new Translation { Id = 2, Locale = "en-US", Text = "America" }
};

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class HiddenProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int NameId { get; set; }

    public int DescriptionId { get; set; }
}

public class ProductRepository
{
    public Product GetProduct(int id, string locale)
    {
        var hidden = hiddenProducts.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);

        if (hidden == null)
            return null;

        var name = translations.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == hidden.NameId && a.Locale == locale);

        var description = translations.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == hidden.DescriptionId && a.Locale == locale);

        if (name == null || description == null)
            return null;

        return new Product { Id = id, Name = name.Text, Description = description.Text };
    }
}

public class Translation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Locale { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

My questions are thus:

- Does this make sense within the Repository Pattern?
- Am I on the right track?
- Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to tell you much about Repository Pattern, but I can tell you something about this code.

You're using LINQ a lot. This might be a good thing, but I would not be too sure about the performance in this particular case. When you use enumerable, you'll need O(n/2) comparisons in the average case O(n) in the worst case. I don't think it makes sense. Typically, what you'd do (especially when some kind of relational database is involved...) for translations of multiple properties would be:

1. Create unique ID for each product (could be GUID, or something)
2. Read the translations for given language (and for this language only) at once. In context of one user, you typically want to display several products in his/her language, surely you do not want to mix languages.
3. `Dictionary<GUID, string>` would be probably more suitable (way shorter lookup time, that is resource consumption) here. But anyway, you'll probably create the translated list of products directly from the record set, where you have unique id and both name and description - it could be done "on the fly".

OK, I believe it was just an example, wasn't it? In general, it is ***way better*** to use common Localization techniques (in case of .Net that means .resx files and stuff) rather than re-inventing the wheel. You're very likely to create an I18n issue(s) unless you really know what you're doing. I can only assure you, that there are reasons behind the translation resources design...
So you really should not be bothered to design your own. 
That is, unless you really need to come up with your own solution, like in case of dynamic translation problem you're showing (in this example translation would be frequently changed and you'd need a simple mechanism to update them and tweak them per customer's needs).

Answer (score 0):

Think about this

```
User: LanguageId

Content: ContentId

Phrase: PhraseId, ContentId
```

Explanation:

User supplies Language. Content Request supplies ContentId. In each language you should have a phrase describing the content.

I think, you somewhere there.